# Basic form validation script

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, form

Is this a good form validation script?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form").submit(function() {

        var shouldSubmit = true;

        $(this).children(":input:not(:button, [type=\"submit\"], [type=\"reset\"])").each(function() {

            if ($(this).val() == "")
            {
                shouldSubmit = false;
                return shouldSubmit;
            }

        });

        if ($("input:checkbox").length > 0)
        {
            if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length == 0)
                shouldSubmit = false;
        }

        if ($("input:radio").length > 0)
        {
            if ($("input:radio:checked").length == 0)
                shouldSubmit = false;
        }

        if (shouldSubmit == false)
            alert("All form fields must be filled out.");

        return shouldSubmit;

    });

});
```

Comment: Have a look at this method: http://api.jquery.com/is/
You can save some work by doing something like `if($("input:radio").is("checked))`. Also you can just return false right away instead of setting a boolean then returning false.

Answer (score 1):

The if statements could be cleaner:

```
    if ($("input:checkbox").length > 0 && $("input:checkbox:checked").length == 0)
    {
        shouldSubmit = false;
    }

    if ($("input:radio").length > 0 && $("input:radio:checked").length == 0)
    {
        shouldSubmit = false;
    }

    if (!shouldSubmit)
    {
        alert("All form fields must be filled out.");
    }
```